# polynomial with integral $0$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $P(x)$ is a polynomial  with real coefficients such that its degree is an odd number and $P(0)\neq 0$. Please help me to prove that exists $a \in  \mathbb  R-\{0\}$ such that  that $$ \int_0^a P(x) dx = 0 $$

Comment: @lulu I think he means that the polynomial's degree is odd, in which case the claim follows (essentially because the behaviour of the polynomial towards $+\infty$ is opposite to its behaviour towards $-\infty$).

Comment: Suppose $p(x)$ has positive leading coefficient and $p(0)<0$. Then $p(x)>0$ for all sufficiently large negative $x$. So $\int_0^ap(x)\ dx$ is negative for small $a$ but positive for large $a$. It is continuous so it must be zero for some $a$. Similarly for the other cases.

Comment: @AlexProvost  I agree, thanks.  I deleted my comment accordingly.

Comment: Note:  I reformatted and edited your question pretty heavily.  Please check to see that I have interpreted it correctly and that I didn't introduce any errors.

Comment: Yes, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, suppose that $p(0) > 0$ and the leading coefficient of $p$ is positive. Then, since the degree of $p$ is odd, $\lim_{x \to -\infty} p(x) = -\infty$. Define a map $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(a) = \int_0^a p(x) dx$. Note that $f$ is continuous by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Also, by continuity of $p$ we have $f(-\epsilon) < 0$ for some small $\epsilon > 0$, and $f(x) > 0$ for $x \ll 0$. Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, there must exist an $a < 0$ such that $f(a) = \int_0^a p(x) dx = 0$.